# K is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $[K: \mathbb{Q}] = p$, with $p$ prime then $Gal_{\mathbb{Q}} K$ is isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The problem asks the following:

If K is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $[K: \mathbb{Q}] = p$, with $p$ prime prove that $Gal_{\mathbb{Q}} K$ is isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the cyclic group of order $p$.

Note that the extension is normal and separable (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is perfect) and so it is Galois.

Therefore we have $|\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})| = [K:\mathbb{Q}] = p$.

The only group of order $p$ is the cyclic group of order $p$.